# Rails: MVC How to use custom actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, model-view-controller

I have a table output from entries using the rails generated scaffold: CRUD ops.

If I want to make another action on the table like the default "Show, Edit, Destory" like a library book "check in", that will update the status to "checked in"...

What would be the proper way to use the model and controller to update? (Using mongodb)

Better stated: What's the best way to have many custom actions? Think of it like many multi purpose "Facebook Likes".

On the table, list of actions "Punch this", "Check out this"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to handle this, but I typically like to isolate actions like this in their own controller action with it's own route.

### Model

To keep things tidy I recommend adding a method to the model that updates the attribute you are concerned about. If you aren't concerned with validation you can use `update_attribute`. This method skips validations and saves to the database

```
class LibraryBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  def check_in!
    self.update_attribute(:checked_in, true)
  end
end
```

### View

You'll need to update the `index.html.erb` view to add the link to update the individual record. This will also require adding a route. Since you are updating the record you will want to use the PUT HTTP verb.

#### routes.rb

```
resources :library_books do
  match :check_in, on: :member, via: :put # creates a route called check_in_library_book
end
```

#### index.html.erb

Add the link

```
link_to check_in_library_book_path(library_book), method: :put
```

### Controller

Now you need to add the action within the controller that calls the `#check_in!` method.

```
class LibraryBooksController < ApplicationController
  def check_in
    @library_book = LibraryBook.find(params[:id])
    if @library_book.check_in!
      # Handle the success
    else
      # Handle the Failure
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'd say this is a good way to do it if your entry will only ever be checked in or not checked in. If that's the case, this way is probably better than my way. If there are more possible statuses than just checked in or not, I think my way is probably better.

Comment: I completely agree. This solution works best for binary conditions on a single object.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to handle status workflows like this is to think about it in terms of **events**, and then just think of status as **most recent event**. I usually create an `event_type` table with a `name` and `code` (so, e.g. `Check In` and `CHECK_IN` for name and code, respectively), and then an `event` table with an `event_type_id`, timestamp, and usually some kind of user id, or IP address, or both.

Then you could say something like this:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events

  def status
    events.order("created_at DESC").first.event_type.name
  end
end
```

There are also "audit trail" gems out there, but in my (limited) experience they aren't very good.

This doesn't speak to MongoDB, and may in fact be incompatible with Mongo, but hopefully it at least points you in the right direction or gives you some ideas.

Comment: How can I add this to the already made "entries" Model and Controller when there's nothing in routes.rb?

Comment: Give your `event` table an `entry_id` (or however you do associations in Mongo). Then, when you want to check an entry in, create a new `CHECK_IN` event that points at that entry. I'd recommend just leaving the `EntriesController` exactly as-is, in accordance with RESTful design philosophy.